# Node process exists even while using

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I'm using `process.on('uncaughtException` to catch errors, log them and prevent the server from going down. However the last part doesn't work and the following code throw an error as excepted and shut down while I'd like it to keep running. The `uncaughtException` callback is well executed but this doesn't prevent the shutdown. How is that possible? Isn't it the purpose of `uncaughtException` ?

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('**************    ERROR     **************', err.message, err.stack);
});
a = 1/  b;
```

This results in

```
$ node index.js 
**************    ERROR     **************
 b is not defined ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/index.js:11:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Your code isn't doing anything else besides generating (and logging) the error, so there's nothing left to do after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is there for undefined variable, not for any un-handled runtime exception. Process.on event should work as you are expecting it to; provided rest of things are right there.

Comment: Ok I was hoping I could catch all kind of errors and not runtime only, but this makes sense!